# Azure Notification Hubs - Send a message from Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, azure-notificationhub

I've been following a Microsoft tutorial on Azure notification hubs and can now send notifications from the Azure control panel to my iOS App successfully.

My next step however is to be able to send these notifications from my Windows Forms Application (C#).  I just can't find any documentation or examples which show how to do this.  In fact I'm struggling to find any examples of how to send an Azure notification at all!

I assume there will be a NuGet package for Azure under WinForms but again no links I have found.  Suggestions most welcome please!

Comment: What have you tried so far? [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) maybe.

Comment: Notification hubs are meant to be used for push notification to mobile phones, and not for windows forms app. Btw here is a sample to send it programmatically using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs NuGet package - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification

Comment: I have found the Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs package and have included it in my project - I'm not trying to send TO a Windows Form application but FROM to a Xamarin Forms iOS App.  I'll take a look at the link you posted - I did find another but it wasn't WinForms...

Comment: It should be independent of your Forms. It also works in a CLI project. And there are in fact various examples. In the sample Solutions of the Azure SDK should be plenty to get "inspired" by.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume there will be a NuGet package for Azure under WinForms but again no links I have found

Yes, we could use the [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) to do that.

The following is the demo code to send the message to iOS platform

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://notificationnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxx", "NotificationHub Name");
string message = "{\"title\":\"((Notification title))\",\"description\":\"Hello from Azure\"}";
hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(message);
```

You also could get more information from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification#send-notifications-from-the-webapi-backend) about how to send message from backend. Although it is related to WebAPI project, I think it is still suit for windows form project.